# Unity3d 5 networking, UNET HLAPI vs LLAPI

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

i used to do a racing game but a year ago i take a break (the project was done on unity 4), since i restart with that project i must reimplement the network because it doesn't work well with the unity 4 network. Now i saw that the are 2 ways to implement it using UNET, the HLAPI and the LLAPI, since the synchronization is very important for me the LLAPI should be better and flexible but i'm here to ask some experts if the effort to use it makes sense or the HLAPI give enough good results.

Comment: You can not use Unity4.  Forget it.  Unity5.  Of course you should use LLAPI.

Comment: That being said, I believe you'll find HLAPI is surprisingly performant.  Note however that if you're writing something as incredibly difficult as real-time predictive racing networking: Regarding the two or three lines of code involved in network communications ... you will, of course, have your system abstract enough that you can test both modes (LLAPI, HLAPI) as you move along, with no effort switching between the two in testing.  If the amount of work you have to do is say "100 units", you will need maybe 0.1 units to test between the two of those!  So, enjoy.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick answer Joe!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's "LLAPI vs HLAPI".

LLAPI is a part of HLAPI. This is the lowest level :

[image]

Everything is flexible.

For example, i'm not using the "highlevel" (Engine Integration) NetworkTransform class, because this is crap, but i'm using the NetworkServer, at a lower level (Connection Management) because it's well done and you can override everything.

So it's not HLAPI vs LLAPI, HLAPI is a Ladder and your just chose which levels can be used "as is"

I know some devs are making their own Serialization, but still using higher levels. Globally it works really well EXCEPT the "Engine Integration" level that is just to me a bad written example (or useful only for card games etc...)